# How do I install SimpleITK on macOS for Anaconda Python 3.6?

Tags: python, anaconda, simpleitk

```
import setuptools
easy_install SimpleITK-0.8.0.post48-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg
```

I downloaded the .egg file and tried using easy_install  but it doesn't seem to be working.  This is the error I am getting.

```
easy_install SimpleITK-0.8.0.post48-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please describe the steps you have taken so far to set up SimpleITK and show us any errors you are seeing.  Check out [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details on how to ask specific questions on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conda install from the SimpleITK channel like this:

```
conda install -c simpleitk simpleitk=1.0.0
```

Comment: This worked, the issue (for future reference) is that I was putting this into the Anaconda shell but you must put it in the macOS shell.  Thanks!